# Select random rows from multiple tables in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert some dummy data into a table (A), for which I need the IDs from two other tables (B and C). How can I get n rows with a random B.Id and a random C.Id.

I've got:

```
 select
 (Select top 1 ID from B order by newid()) as 'B.Id',
 (select top 1 ID from C order by newid()) as 'C.Id'
```

which gives me random Ids from each table, but what's the best way to get n of these? I've tried joining on a large table and doing top n, but the IDs from B and C are the same random Ids repeated for each row.

So looking to end up with something like this, but able to specify N rows.

```
INSERT INTO A (B-Id,C-Id,Note)
 select
 (Select top 1 ID from B order by newid()) as 'B.Id',
 (select top 1 ID from C order by newid()) as 'C.Id',
'Rar'
```

So if B had Ids 1,2,3,4 and C had Ids 11,12,13,14, i'm after the equivalent of:

```
INSERT INTO A (B-Id,C-Id,Note)
Values
(3,11,'rar'), (1,14,'rar'),(4,11,'rar')
```

Where the Ids from each table are combined at random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicates, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values in each table (randomly) and then join them:

```
select b.id as b_id, c.id as c_id
from (select b.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
     on b.seqnum = c.seqnum;
```

You can just add `top N` or `where seqnum <= N` to limit the number.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you want `N` random rows from the union of the two tables - so on any given execution you will get `X` rows from table `B` and `N-X` rows from table `C`.  To accomplish this, you first `UNION` tables `B` and `C` together, then `ORDER BY` the random value generated by `NEWID()` while pulling your overall `TOP N`.

```
SELECT TOP 50 --or however many you like
    DerivedUnionOfTwoTables.[ID],
    DerivedUnionOfTwoTables.[Source]
FROM 
    (
    (SELECT NEWID() AS [Random ID], [ID], 'Table B' AS [Source] FROM B)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT NEWID() AS [Random ID], [ID], 'Table C' AS [Source] FROM C)
    ) DerivedUnionOfTwoTables
ORDER BY 
    [Random ID] DESC
```

I included a column showing which source table any given record comes from so you could see the distribution of the two table sources changing each time it is executed.  If you don't need it and/or don't care to verify, simply comment it out from the topmost select.

Comment: Sorry, question wasn't very clear. I didn't want to union the IDs, I wanted a random ID from B and a random Id from C to insert into one row of A, e.g.:
INSERT INTO A (B-Id,C-Id,Note)
 select
 (Select top 1 ID from B order by newid()) as 'B.Id',
 (select top 1 ID from C order by newid()) as 'C.Id'

Comment: @Matt No worries.  I didn't get you were looking to randomly PAIR rows from `B` and `C`.  If that's the case, it looks like Gordon's answer will best suit you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to join to a large table - `Select top N ID from B order by newid()` should work as `newid()` works per-row (unlike `RAND()`).  Your join is probably doing a cross-join which will give you multiple results for each `newid` value.