# PostgreSQL Pick one single random row from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can we pick a random row from 3 tables, whereas the table row count for each table may vary. This would need to be fair if there not same count. This means if one table had only one row and the other table has 10 rows, then were much more likely get row from table with 10 rows. Each row in all tables get chance at winning

I was trying to convert this SQL code which I got from another Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159178/select-random-rows-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

```
 SELECT preview_id, review_id
 FROM (
     select preview.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum from
     preview
 ) preview 
   JOIN (
      select review.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum 
      from review
   ) review ON preview.seqnum = review.seqnum;
```

3 Table schemas.

```
CREATE TABLE preview
(
preview_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
preview_header VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
preview_text TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header One', '"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.");
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Two', '"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don''t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn''t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.");
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Three', '"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Four', '"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" );
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Five', '"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?");
INSERT INTO preview(preview_header, preview_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Six', '"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.");


CREATE TABLE article
(
article_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
article_header VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
article_text TEXT NOT NULL
);
SELECT * FROM article;
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header One', '"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.");
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header Two', '"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don''t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn''t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.");
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header Three', '"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header Four', '"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?");
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header Five', '"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?");
INSERT INTO article(article_header, article_text) VALUES ('Article Header Six', '"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.");

CREATE TABLE review
(
review_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
review_header VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
review_text TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header One', '"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains." );
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Two', '"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don''t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn''t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.");
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Three', '"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." );
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Four', '"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?");
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Five', '"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" );
INSERT INTO review(review_header, review_text) VALUES ('Preview Header Six', '"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.");
```

The desired result will be a single full row from any one these tables. So each row has a fair chance at been the winner

Comment: table structure is the same between the tables?

Comment: replace `order by newid()` with `order by random()`

Comment: Ya structure is exactly same. I'm trying answer below at moment.

Comment: Structure not same actually now i think of it. Different names for columns in eah table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tables has similar structure just use `UNION ALL`

```
 SELECT *,
        row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
 FROM ( SELECT preview.* FROM preview
        UNION ALL
        SELECT review.* FROM review
      ) T
```

if doesnt have similar structure you need to do some tricks to make the union with same number of columns.

```
 SELECT *,
        row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
 FROM ( SELECT 'preview' as `source`, p.field1, p.field2, null    , null 
        FROM preview P
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'review'  as `source`, null    , null    , r.field1, r.field2
        FROM review R
      ) T
```

EDIT: for you new request

```
 SELECT *, row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
 FROM (SELECT 'preview' as `source`, preview_id as winning_id
       FROM `preview`
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'article' as `source`, article_id
       FROM `preview`
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'review'  as `source`, review_id
       FROM `preview`           
      ) T
 --LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It has same structure except column names... Im gonna try this now.

Comment: you can also use the fake column to know where the row came from `'preview' as source`

Comment: Why T at end? Whats about ? do i put semi colon after the T?

Comment: T is  an alias for the subquery between `()` so you can refer as a `Table` can be any name you want

Comment: ERROR:  UNION types boolean and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched

Comment: checking tables now, thought they was same, maybe i small bit off, i cam arrange them same

Comment: Yes, or use the other query.  Try to use just a small set of columns to test is working and then you finish the whole column later

Comment: how do i rank this answers, how does it work, this is perfect answer and has been very helpful, also its new question, i couldn't find answer to this question , hence i posted
I ask as i did tick and press up on another answer yesterday and it didnt do anything it seems

Comment: what you mean rank? if you want upvote or mark the answer as correct will appear a green check.

Comment: Thanks very much . Well received :)

Comment: Says :
ERROR:  function newid() does not exist
LINE 2: OVER (order by newid()) as seqnum
Now that i try again

Comment: try with `(order by random())`,  `newid()` is for `sql_server`. I tought you already try it before and trust you :p

Comment: Ok thanks very much. This just makes two lots of preview? No review rows at all

Comment: Can you elaborate? not sure what you mean. Your tittle say select one random row.... but you query is different... bring a random row from each table and show it together... I did the first

Comment: The result is all 6 of my preview rows x 2. No review at all.
So 2 duplicates of preview rows. I can give you access to a database if you would like. Its only practice database so not important

Comment: show me a picture? or create a sample in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: the columsn names are different, should i use secod option if columns name are different.. example
review_header from review
preview_header from preview
article_header from article

Comment: maybe thats what you meant by not same, like the only thing that can be different is table name,,,?

Comment: Update your question with a db schema, sample data and expected output. your link doesnt work.

Comment: what do i do with the fiddle thing, i pasted code in and hit buyild

Comment: when you run, he create a link. just post the new link

Comment: Well there is two fields, left and right, both dont do anything. I put stuff in left hit build, says built, but nothing.. i put stuff in right, says running, then nothing. link in url has nothing in it

Comment: Check my link again? put one create table one insert on the left, build the schema then a select on the right and press run. A new link will be created. And with every run a new version of the link is created

Comment: Now you add the inserts?

Comment: so this is basic version to try,,, so we need a random single row from all tables. 
So any row in any table has a fair and equal chance at been picked

Comment: so what will you do with the row after that?

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for taking so much your time. I do really appreciate any tips or help i recieve

Comment: that row will be used.... I basically have a home page that at random displays either a article, preview or review

Comment: Each one these tables has lotf of other tables such as like, shares, ratings, etc. Ill be also trying to pull them with this random pick

Comment: See you should start for that. Please insert some data and I finish it.

Comment: I could do this in the java before i make the call. Lets say articles has 25 rows, reviews had 50 rows and preview has 25 rows. I would first develop some kind of dice that firstly decides what table ill use then just use a easier random select from a single table. The java dice would need to be fair as to give the review 50/100 chance at winning while the other two 25/100 chance at winning

Comment: So are you saying i should enter the full sc hema and request rather than starting it easier, ok ill just be 5 minutes

Comment: No... just add some insert to the simple schema.

Comment: Check my edit. Just need get a `source` and `winning_id`. Then you do another select of the source table with that id to get all the field. Will need two query but that way you dont have to worry about different schemas between tables.

Comment: i mean it wont let me enter the data, i built the schema but entering all the fake data wont work, keeps saying things are not there that are there, i tried lets say, enetering app_user's first, runs ok, but then entering reviews, with app_user as foreign key, says app_user doens texsist

Comment: Yes, sometimes fail, just need to way some minutes.

Comment: are you able to connect to actual data base, using lets say PJAdmin

Comment: it wont let me query to saee of users are in there,

Comment: i use
SELECT * FROM app_user;
get nothing to look at

Comment: is there no output pane?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 2:  FROM (SELECT 'preview' as `source`, preview_id as winning_i...
                                   ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 88

Comment: Something is working man WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. removed them quote things. seems to be working, its doing something